# Remove one parameter name and value in url using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Existing Url

```
http://example.com/home.php?id=1&branch_id=4&course_id=5
```

New url

```
http://example.com/home.php?id=1&branch_id=4
```

removing course_id from existing url

How to remove one parameter value from url.

Tried below code:

```
function replaceUrlParam(url, paramName, paramValue){
    var pattern = new RegExp('(\\?|\\&)('+paramName+'=).*?(&|$)')
    var newUrl=url
    if(url.search(pattern)>=0){
        newUrl = url.replace(pattern,'$1$2' + paramValue + '$3');
    }
    else{
        newUrl = newUrl + (newUrl.indexOf('?')>0 ? '&' : '?') + paramName + '=' + paramValue
    }
    return newUrl
}
```

but its not working...

Comment: `.replace(/[&?]course_id=\d+/, '')`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fc0q69dd/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you said that you want to use variable instead of directly using `.replace(/&course_id=\d+/, '')`, you can do it like below:-

Example:-

```js
var re = new RegExp("&course_id=\\d+");
var newUrl="http://example.com/home.php?id=1&branch_id=4&course_id=5";
console.log(newUrl.replace(re, ''));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: change the code :  function RemoveParam(c) {
              var re = new RegExp("[&\?]"+ c +"=\\d+");} and it work perfectly, thak you for your help..

Comment: @Ranju  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do that by using this code to remove `&course_id=5`:

```
var url = "http://example.com/home.php?id=1&branch_id=4&course_id=5";
url.replace(/([&\?]course_id=5*$|course_id=5&|[?&]course_id=5(?=#))/, '');
```

It will return you: `http://example.com/home.php?id=1&branch_id=4`